# How to keep custom attribute in styled component?

Tags: styled-components

I created a simple styled component with a custom property `test`, but when rendered, the `test` property just did not appear in the div dom, what happened?

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div<{
    test?: boolean;
}>`
    color:red;
`;
```

```
//in render function...
<StyledDiv test>it's just test</StyledDiv>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In React boolean value is not passed to the dom element in means that `test` or `test={true}` will not be available to the dom. It only supports three types of `string`, `number` and `object` and it will convert those to `string` so all you need to do is change it too `test=""` and it will work.

If you are looking to access the prop `test` in your component you need to do something like this:

```js
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    color: ${({test}) => test ? 'red' : 'blue'};
`;
```

Comment: how to do if i want the `test` appeared on that dom. cause i have a selector to access that dom by that attribute

Comment: pass a value with it react doesn't support boolean values something like this: `test=""` would do. I will also change my answer.

Comment: still not got `test` on the dom,the final dom is look like this  `<div class="sc-fzXfLO bJxAYn">it's just test</div>` . what i want is `<div class="sc-fzXfLO bJxAYn" test="">it's just test</div>`.  it looks styled components only keep the `HTMLAttributes`, so if i use `data-test`, it can be keeped.